# Javafx: Combo-Box popup control

Tags: combobox, javafx, tableview

I have a javafx combo-box with a table-view as its pop-up control. The issue is when I click on the column header for sorting, the pop-up disappears. How can I restrict the pop-up to go only when I select a row from the table view?

Comment: can you post your sample code. So that it will be easy for us to give the solution.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question one way to check table row is selected or not is

`tableName.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex()`

This returns -1 when no row is selected.

Another way is

`ObservableList<SomeDataType> selectedItems= tableName.getItems();`

This returns multiple selected rows If observable list is empty then no row is selected.